# What is the best way to include babel polyfill using multiple entry points

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm using a webpack config using multiple entry points:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.[hash].js');

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        main: './resources/assets/js/main.js',
        services: './resources/assets/js/services.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: './public/assets/web/js',
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        publicPath: '/assets/web/js/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'web_modules', 'modules']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/, /web_modules/],
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                stage: 0
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [commonsPlugin,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        function() {
            this.plugin('done', function(stats) {
                fs.writeFile('./cache.json', JSON.stringify({
                    hash: stats.hash
                }));
            });
        }
    ]
};
```

Is there any way to include the **[babel polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)** in my webpack config. Or what is the best way to include it in my setup?

Do I have to include it as a require in all my modules?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change

```
main: './resources/assets/js/main.js',
services: './resources/assets/js/services.js'
```

to be

```
main: ['babel-polyfill', './resources/assets/js/main.js'],
services: ['./resources/assets/js/services.js']
```

so that the polyfill is loaded and executed as part of each entry point without your files needing to know about it.

This assumes that both `main` and `services` are loaded on the same page. If they are two separate pages, you'd want the `babel-polyfill` entry in both arrays.

#### Note

The above applies to Babel 5. For Babel 6, you'd `npm install --save babel-polyfill` and use `babel-polyfill` instead of `babel/polyfill`.

Comment: Why did you use  --save-dev and not --save?

Comment: Generally you wouldn't be building your JS in your production environment, you'd compile once before deployment with your development dependencies, and then in production you don't need any of your webpack packages.

Comment: This will fail if you are using both entry points on the same page ( `Uncaught Error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed` )

Comment: Since polyfill actually mutates the globals you would technically only need it on one file.  If `main` is loaded first in all cases, then it seems to be the winner. (just a guess, not sure)

Comment: Right, I was assuming it was two independent entry points for two separate pages. I guess that's not guaranteed though.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you have a multi-entry application, would you have to include the "babel-polyfill" for each entry point in your `webpack.config.js` AND include the `import babel-polyfill` at the top of each of your entry point JS files?

Comment: @wmock: Nope, Having babel-polyfill added to webpack entry is sufficient and you dont need to import this on every other files!

Comment: For Babel 7, the npm scoped polyfill entry path would be `main: ['@babel/polyfill', './resources/assets/js/main.js']`

Answer (score 8):

An alternative for development (perhaps not the best setup for production) would be to have `babel-polyfill` in its own module:

```
entry: {
    'babel-polyfill': ['babel-polyfill'],
    main: './resources/assets/js/main.js',
    services: './resources/assets/js/services.js'
}
```

Background: I tried the suggestion in the answer above and was still getting an error: "Only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed". I'm using webpack 2 so maybe that's a factor. The above solution is fine for my purposes since I'm writing a reusable library to be included in larger apps, and just want a separate demo bundle in the library repo for testing purposes. But for a full app, it might not be a good idea to require an extra HTTP request to load the polyfill in production unless you're using HTTP/2.