# Transpiling ES6 for IE11 with Babel

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm new to babel and trying to transpile my es6 code to work with IE11.  But when I run the code in IE11 I get js errors about my `forEach` code.  From what I've read I needed to add the preset `@babel/preset-env`. I added that to my config file so I'm not sure why it's not transpiling those `forEach` calls.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        setupForm: "./Scripts/es6/setupForm.js",
        prelimForm: "./Scripts/es6/prelimForm.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/build'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I thought that perhaps I needed to additionally reference the babel `polyfill.js` as [discussed here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) so I added it to my page, however, I'm getting the same error about **Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'**.

Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "OurSite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "map_embed.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add `entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./Scripts/es6/setupForm.js"],` to your webpack entry configuration?

Comment: No.  Because I have two files in my entry, how would I translate what you have to each file?

Comment: That depends on whether the two outputs will be on the same page or not. If they are on separate pages, you need to add the polyfill on both: `entry: {setupForm: ['@babel/polyfill','./Scripts/es6/setupForm.js']}` etc

Comment: No they won't be on the same page.  I tried doing this - setupForm: ["@babel-polyfill", "./Scripts/es6/setupForm.js"] - for the first one.  But when running npm run build, I get an error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-polyfill'"  Do I need to replace the @ symbol with ./node_modules?

Comment: No, you need to keep the `@`, are you sure you have `@babel/polyfill` installed as a package?

Comment: According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380063/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-babel-polyfill-using-multiple-entry-points), the person said you need to use babel-polyfill instead of babel/polyfill.  This is what I have - node_modules/babel-polyfill - in the root of the project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194457/discussion-between-yoav-kadosh-and-geoff-swartz).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [babel polyfill being included, but forEach still doesn't work in IE11 on NodeLists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331180/babel-polyfill-being-included-but-foreach-still-doesnt-work-in-ie11-on-nodelis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you should do:

- Install `@babel/polyfill`
- Include `@babel/polyfill` in your `entry` (If you have more than 1 entry, and you don't plan to have both on the same page, include the polyfill in both)
- Make sure all babel packages have the same **major** version, i.e. `7.x.x` (don't worry about `babel-loader` - that's actually a webpack package, not a babel package).

Webpack

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        setupForm: ["@babel/polyfill", "./Scripts/es6/setupForm.js"],
        prelimForm: ["@babel/polyfill", "./Scripts/es6/prelimForm.js"]
    },
    ...
}
```

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: As a follow up, a portion of my problem was that I was using forEach on a nodelist and not an array.  This helped solve that issue -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331180/babel-polyfill-being-included-but-foreach-still-doesnt-work-in-ie11-on-nodelis

Answer (score 11):

As of Babel 7.4.0 `@babel/polyfill` has been deprecated in favour of `core-js` and `regenerator` packages.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#docsNav

Either include in webpack

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: [
      'core-js/stable',
      'regenerator-runtime/runtime',
      'src/main.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

OR include in your js at the top

```js
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

Comment: See also [this updated SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54490329/6069586) on migrating from polyfill to this.