# Javascript/Jquery Errors in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I’ve done most of my programming debugging my website with chrome and recently took a look at the results in Internet explorer.  The errors I’m getting do not show up in chrome.  I believe I got each of these code snippets from other accepted answers here on stack overflow.  Any help they can be given would certainly be appreciated.  I did do some research and the Internet explorer (11) solution was not immediate for me

[image: Sleep]

[image: Key Value]

[image: Async]

Comment: IE doesn't support arrow functions, await, for/of, and much more ... you need Babel here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpiling ES6 for IE11 with Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446904/transpiling-es6-for-ie11-with-babel)

Comment: ECMAScript 6 - compatibility:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Thank you - I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors in the pictures are all due to IE doesn't support ES6/ES7 syntax. If you require ES6 features in Internet Explorer 11, check out a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Here's [an article](https://medium.com/@SunnyB/how-to-convert-es6-into-es5-using-babel-1b533d31a169) about how to use babel to convert ES6 into ES5, please check it out.

1. [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility):

You should transpile it using Bable or change the syntax like below:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    return setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

2. [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility):

You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016327/how-to-make-promises-work-in-ie11) about making promise work in IE. You could use a 3rd party promise library like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

3. [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility):

You need to add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill) for it to work in IE 11:

```
if (!Object.entries) {
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];
    
    return resArray;
  };
}
```

4. [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility):

You can use [facebook/regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator) to polyfill async/await in IE 11.

> You could follow the steps to support async/await in IE 11:
>
> - use [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env)
> - `yarn add regenerator` or `npm install regenerator`
> - add `node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (10.7kb minified)` into your bundle

Reference link: [Add ES7 Async/Await Support for your Webapp in 3 Easy Steps](https://medium.com/@zwacky/add-es7-async-await-support-into-your-non-bleeding-edge-build-process-ad0dded0d002)

Comment: Your solution is very good and I can see the references that would make it work. However, I could not get it to work with webpack. I'm no webpack expert and frankly don't like webpack. The solution I ended up using was converting my elements to bootstrap carousels to create the same effect. It created the delays I needed without having to install god knows how many babel and webpack packages.